# Getting all possible sequences from Data using R

Tags: r, sequence, traminer

Considering a time stamped event data like this:

```
Time(s)  Event
 1         a
 1.5       b
 2         b
 3         a
 5.6       b
```

Is there any algorithm in R which can provide me all possible sequences
Note: I have tried Traminer and arulesSequences, for which you have to define some basket size that you are looking for a sequences within 1 hour or so.

Any leads will be appreciated to get a result like:

```
Seq Count avg_time
 a     2   a
 b     3   b
 ab    2   a-1.55-b
 ba    1   b-1-a
 bb    1   b-.5-b
 abb   1   a-.5-b-.5-b
 abba  1   a-.5-b-.5-b-1-a
 bbab  1   b-.5-b-1-a-2.6-b
 abbab 1   a-.5-b-.5-b-1-a-2.6-b
```

Comment: Why isn't `bb` a sequence?

Comment: it shld be 
i missed it
updated

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli, it seems to be (0.5 + 2.6) / 2.

Comment: exactly! as ab sequence is coming 2 times so i have taken the average

Comment: shouldnt there be a seq for aa seq too `a-1.5-a`.